# Can't install lua on 12.04 on Chrome book

Tags: 12.04, installation, lua

I am currently trying to install lua on my Ubuntu 12.04 on Chrome book and I keep getting this error:

[image: Embed image]

I'm doing good learning different programming languages (self taught) and well I wanted to start learning Lua. That error is keeping me from doing that unfortunately. I've tried doing it with and without of root access and still no success.

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem or of a different way of installing Lua?

Thanks a ton! Don't mind the top of the image just me taking out my frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer is connected to internet, Just try following command.

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.2
```

It will install lua5.2 from official ubuntu repository. It's easy way of installing packages on ubuntu.

Comment: Hi jokerdino and Chan-Ho Suh, do you guys really feel that someone can copy "sudo apt-get install" like command from someone else's comment? It's very first lesson in ubuntu CLI and I tried this on my own machine and then copied same text as answer.